# Windows DPI scaling woes

Tags: windows, mfc, dpi, highdpi

In Window 10, using MFC, I have a dialog in my app that displays at different sizes in different situations. In "Simple" mode it's a fixed size with fixed sized content, in 'Advanced' mode its re-sizable with (some) resizable elements.

I'm trying to make allow for high DPI situations and DPI scaling not equal to 100%. I'm using a simple scaling factor equal to the DPI scaling (e.g., *1.5 for 150%, etc.) It's not perfect, but works adequately at 100%, 150% and 200%. However, at 125% and 175% something doesn't quite work, and setting my dialog to the fixed size makes it too small for its content. It's almost like it doesn't scale equally in both directions.

Now I could tailor my size/scaling adjustment individually to each DPI scaling setting - but I'm not sure how that would work if the user picks a custom %.

Does anyone have any insight into what is wrong / how to do this correctly?

**EDIT...some screenshots:**

You can see that none of the dialogs are unusable, but 125 and 175 are a little worse in terms of fitting.

100% [image: 100%]

125% [image: 125%]

150% [image: 150%]

175% [image: 175%]

200% [image: 200%]

Comment: I have solved some hard DPI issues for my own team's product.  I'm happy to help.  But I really need a [mcve] to offer suggestions.  Can you elaborate on what "something doesn't quite work" means"?  Can you post a sample program that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Showing some pictures might definitely be helpful.

Comment: I honestly did want to help. But without the mcve (or at least some code being show) and OP not following up, there's not much I can do.  Let me know...

Comment: I am seeing a very similar issue. Can easily reproduce. Just set scaling initially to 200% (recommended) create the dialog with some static text and edit fields. Do Format | Size to Content on the static texts. Then close VS. Switch laptop to 175% and run the app. Statics get truncated and weirdly if you open the project in VS then editor also shows them as truncated. Have raised issue on this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/issue-with-mfc-sizing-when-using-scaling-factors-l/1606266